# Transition from Facebook Offline Conversion API to Conversion API Deduplication

Tags: facebook-events, facebook-conversions-api

With Facebook ‘Offline Conversion API’ being deprecated next year, we have been looking to transition to ‘Conversion API’ which supports Offline Events.

We’re mainly looking at uploading Offline Event for event name ‘Purchase’ with the action source for ‘Physical_Store’. If we upload the same list we had in ‘Offline Conversion API’ to ‘Conversion API’ will Facebook automatically deduplicate previous entries already entered in via ‘Offline Conversion API’?

In the list to upload there is an ‘orderID’ and ‘event time’. I know each system deduplicates entries previously entered in its own API when these two fields are present. However, can ‘Conversion API’ deduplicate entries already entered via ‘Offline Conversion API’ previously?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you provide an unique event_id